# Fetching NULL data from database showing as "null" string in laravel-vue project

Tags: laravel, forms, vue.js, vuejs2, fetch

for example if I fetch users data as these params

```
first_name -> john
last_name -> null
```

when I want to fill inputs (or span , p , .. ) I want to show null data as empty string but it showing as "null" string

```
<h3 class="dahsboard__sidebar__header__name">{{userData.first_name +' '+ userData.last_name}}</h3>
```

it shows as :

```
"jhon null"
```

i found a way to prevent this by doing this in axios:

```
this.userData = res.data;
for(let user in this.userData){
            if(this.userData[user]=='null' || this.userData[user]==null){
                this.userData[user] = '';
            }
        }
```

in the above code `this.userData` is all the users data that i fetch using axios
but I'm looking for a better (professional) way to do it

my Api request is something like this :

```
$user = Auth::user();
return \response()->json([
        'first_name' => $user->name,
        'last_name' => $user->last_name,
        'email' => $user->email,
        'avatar'=>$path //don't mind the avatar 
    ],200);
```

Comment: Well, what does your API request in Laravel look like? How is Laravel returning the `userData`? Clearly something is amiss there.

Comment: @JustCarty
i edited my question and added  API request

Comment: @JustCarty
he used || operation that I already tried but didn't work, however, I can rewrite the solution that I'm using right now with fewer codes with the || operation that's the only help I could get from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you try and concatenate a string in JavaScript, against a `null` value, JavaScript will use loose conversion to convert `null` into `"null"`.

To avoid this problem, you have many options, but I think the simplest is to just use two separate prints.

```
<h3 class="dahsboard__sidebar__header__name">
    {{ userData.first_name }} {{ userData.last_name }}
</h3>
```

This way, you avoid the concatenation problem, since if each one of these are null they will print nothing.
I've not actually tested this, but it should work, unless the Vue compiler breaks it!

Comment: it was the best answer so far plus I found the PHP operation "??" useful in my API I changed my API to `'last_name' => $user->last_name ?? ' '`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h3 class="dahsboard__sidebar__header__name">
    {{ (userData.first_name ?? '') + ' ' + (userData.last_name ?? '') }}
</h3>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: Nah mate it's not gonna work in Vue plus the  "??" operation doesn't get proper support from some of the browsers

Answer (score 0):

in your API, you should be able to have something like:

`$user->last_name ? $user->last_name : ''`

Comment: it works fine when i changed my API to this : 
`'last_name' => $user->last_name ? '': $user->last_name` 
  
but I'm really looking for a better way to do it because I feel like I'm going to code a lot if I try to use this solution in my entire project

Comment: In that case, don't store null values in your DB, and set your last name column to default to empty string

Answer (score 0):

User Migration should allow null values, make you migration as follows

```
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->text('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->text('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->text('email')->unique();
        $table->text('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

the eloquent query for fetch the data

```
    $user = Auth::user();
    return \response()->json([
            'first_name' => $user->name,
            'last_name' => $user->last_name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'avatar'=>$path //don't mind the avatar
        ],200);
```

on your, Axios use foreach. null value will not show

```
     res.data.forEach((element) => {
        console.log({
          first_name: element.first_name,
          last_name: element.last_name,
          email: element.email,
        });
      });

      output : jhon
```